# Generating correct SQL with a Converter that converts to NULL?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, jpql

I have a named query:

```
<query>
        select data 
        from objects obj
        where obj.status = :status
</query>
```

The thing is that status is a `Boolean` parameter that is converted by means of an `AttributeConverter` to either "+" if status is `true`or `NULL` if status is `false`.

I do this through a `javax.persistence.Converter.AttributeConverter<Boolean, String>`

This works fine if status is `true` but if it is `false` I get an error:

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

I can see in the error log that the generated SQL query contains the following expression:

> (t0.STATUS = ?)

This is incorrect, because it should actually be: `(t0.STATUS IS NULL)

I was expecting for JPQL to automatically generate the expected query if the value is converted to `NULL`. Is there a way to accomplish this or are converters not meant to be used in this way?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use NVL:

```sql
where nvl(status, 'not_real_value') = nvl(:status, 'not_real_value')
```

This common solution has few problems:

1. You must be sure that 'not_real_value' could not happend
2. you almost opt-out of using indexes (unless you use function index) on status column

so here is another solution without any compromizes:

```sql
where ((:status is not null and status = :status) 
   or (status is null and :status is null))
```

Comment: While this trickery is possible it was exactly what I was trying to avoid. Alas, it seems there is no way around it.